# Would adding dropout help reduce overfitting when following tensorflow's transfer learning example?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using the pretrained tensorflow inception v3 model and transfer learning to do some image classification on a new image training set I have. I'm following the instructions laid out here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html

However, I'm getting some severe overfitting (training accuracy is in the high 90s but CV/test accuracy is in the 50s).

Besides doing some image augmentation to try to increase my training sample size, I was wondering if doing some dropout in the retrain phase might help.

I am using this file (that came with tensorflow) as the base/template for my retraining/transfer learning:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py

Looking at the inception v3 model, dropout is in there. However, I don't see any dropout added in the retrain.py file.

Does it make sense that I could try to add dropout to the retraining to solve my overfitting? If so, where would I add that? If not, why?

Thanks

Comment: I got some good improvement adding dropout to the retrain.py source. If you want to try it, you can reference my forked script here: https://github.com/maxmelnick/tensorflow/blob/no_random/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py. It has some additional updates, but the main part you should look at starts on line 784.

Comment: Tensorflow has updated the `retrain.py` , do we still need to add dropout?

Answer (score 0):

From Max's comment above, which was a good answer:

Max got some good improvement adding dropout to the retrain.py source. If you want to try it, you can reference his [forked script](https://github.com/maxmelnick/tensorflow/blob/no_random/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py). It has some additional updates, but the main part you should look at starts on line 784